# Finding "quiet" areas in images

Tags: c#, opencv, accord.net

I'm wanting to take an image, and add a description over the top of the image, with a box behind the text to ensure the text can be easily read. I'd like to add the description over a portion of the image that does not have a lot of activity / detail, e.g. a portion of grass, if there's a picture of a dog in the foreground.

Using either Accord or OpenCV, how can I find quiet areas to place the box and description over?

Comment: Read about [visual saliency](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Visual_salience).

Comment: I was thinking it may be easier than that, maybe something like using the concentration of lines in an area.

Comment: The topic is still visual saliency. You can start from early approaches, like mentioned in [this section](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Visual_salience#Simple_computational_framework).